# Activity background becomes black on ldpi density

Tags: android

I have a simple activity with a few lines. I am testing the app on ldpi density and my problem is that it appears completely black, however

**1. It works fine on mdpi and hdpi density**

**2. I can see in the graphical view of the xml the desired design**

Half of the layout is red, the other half is green, and there are texts in the middle.
My code is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:fillViewport="true" >

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FF0000" //red
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#00FF01" //green
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="380dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/bal"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv0"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="62dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="62dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="52dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="52dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="42dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv5"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="42dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv6"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv7"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="380dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/bal"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv8"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:text="A"
                android:textColor="#000000"
                android:textSize="62dp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv9"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="62dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv10"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="52dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv11"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="52dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv12"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="42dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv13"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="42dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:text="A" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv15"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="32dp"
                    android:text="B" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>



    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

if I set android:background="#FFFFFF" to scrollview background, I get a white bg with the black texts.
if I set it to android:background="#000000" (as it is in mdpi and hdpi layouts, but I removed it now) I see nothing just pure blackness, since now both the bg and the texts are black. Same happens when I set no background color to the scrollview.

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea but it turned out the scrollview was behind the whole thing. I removed it and everything works fine. Strange.